# Where to get the drivers for AVerMedia AVerTV Digi Volar X A815?

Tags: drivers

Does anyone knows where can I find the *AVERMEDIA VOLAR DVBT MODEL A815* drivers?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/AVerMedia_AVerTV_Digi_Volar_X_%28A815%29

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly supported in Linux, even the IR remote.  Its very powerful at bad conditions but not stable for 24x7 use.

First thing, you need to copy the following firmware [dvb-usb-af9015.fw](http://www.otit.fi/~crope/v4l-dvb/af9015/af9015_firmware_cutter/firmware_files/4.95.0/dvb-usb-af9015.fw) in your `/lib/firmware/` directory.  This is now part of the dvb-v4l dev tree and if you are compiling from mercurial snapshots this will be done for you.

The driver is supported in the latest v4l-dvb, so you have to download them first. Either getting or using mercury See the [How to Obtain, Build and Install V4L-DVB Device Drivers](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers) for all the details.

The latest development version of the driver gives support to the RM-FP remote control. But there are other remote control versions bundled with the device. RM-KS is one of those.

Download and compile the drivers, and then use the option `remote=5 when dvb-usb-af9015` module is loaded. This is made adding (as root) a file called, for example, dvb, in the directory `/etc/modprobe.d/` with the line

```
options dvb_usb_af9015 remote=5
```

For LIRC Configuration, first step is to identify the file device associated with our dvb-t device. This is made by command:

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -n10 a815
```

This command will display an output like this:

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=07ca Product=a815 Version=0200
N: Name="IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:13.2-4/ir0
S: Sysfs=/class/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event8
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3c0110 10200000000000 0 8400 90c0300801 1e060000000000 ffc
```

The information that you need is the input device number that in this case is `/class/input/input8` This means that the device associated with the IR is

```
/dev/input/event8
```

ATTENTION! The device number change from PC to other. So this is only an EXAMPLE. So we must modify the lirc configuration that is in `/etc/sysconfig/lircd` or `/etc/lirc/hardware.conf` (change from distribution to other) this parameters:

```
...
DRIVER="devinput"
...
DEVICE="/dev/input/event8"
...
```

Second step is to generate the codes list by lirc tools. ATTENTION! the files provided by lirc in folder `/usr/share/lirc-remotes/avermedia/` not work every time so we need to generate a file manually. We need to stop lirc first by this command:

```
/etc/init.d/lircd stop
```

Now we can generate the `/etc/lircd.conf` with `irrecord` by this command:

```
irrecord -H dev/input -f -d /dev/input/eventX ~/lircd.conf
cp ~/lircd.conf /etc/
```

but first you must replace the X with the number of the device. In my case I have `/dev/input/event8` so I put 8. Follow the instructions on screen for build the file. Press RETURN then old down any key of remote control for find GAP value. If the device chosen its right you can see a progressive dot displaying. We gap search is done we must put a name for the key and press ENTER and then the relative button on remote control. This for all key in the remote control. To end the procedure we con press ENTER.

Some distribution need the file in `/etc/lirc/` so we can copy the file in this way:

```
cp /etc/lircd.conf /etc/lirc/
```

Finally we restart `lirc` with:

```
/etc/init.d/lircd restart
```

We can use the `LIRC` front-end `irkick` for settings the remote control keys or build manually the ~/.lircrc file.

Due to some problems with the HID devices, in some machines the IR reception is buggy, to solve this, you can create the file `/etc/modprobe.d/usbhid` containing:

```
options usbhid quirks=0x07ca:0xa815:0x04
```

and then execute

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and reboot. The problem should be solved that way.

Once compiled you can try this: [Testing_your_DVB_device](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Testing_your_DVB_device).  Kaffeine seems the easiest/fastest way to check if it works.

<sup>Source:[LinuxTV](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/AVerMedia_AVerTV_Digi_Volar_X_%28A815%29)</sup>